# Delphi FireMonkey TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.GetDevicesByMediaType(TMediaType.Video) always returns empty list

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using code from this wiki
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Video_Capturing

but

```
TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.GetDevicesByMediaType(TMediaType.Video);
```

Always returns empty list (i have webcam attached and other apps see it).
Googling didn't give me any responses.

Could you please tell me what could cause this problem, as this component is critical for my project.

Comment: Windows development?

Answer (score 0):

Video capture devices which are VideoForWindows (unlikey as this is ancient and long since superceded) or DirectShow (ie: do not have kernel drivers) rely on user mode DLLs.  If you have such a device and are compiling for 32/64 bit and do not have DLLs to match then the devices will not be returned in the enumeration.

If you have other software on the system which does detect the devices then switching your target platform between 32/64 bit will likely reveal the device.  If this is the case, you do not have drivers for the device which match the bitness of the platform target.  The solution is to either change your build target, to find appropriate drivers from the manufacturer, or to choose a different webcam.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. But changing target platform doesn't made any difference to me :(

Comment: Try with lots of  different webcams. Your users are going to have different one's so you might as well get a few now to see how they don't all behave the same. I am speaking for experience here.